# Output difference of 2 txt files to a 3rd txt file

Tags: cmd, diff, filecompare

I'm trying to run a bat file that will compare 1 file to another and output the differences

I've tried using gnu diff utilites, fc, and endless googleing to find a solution but I cant seem to figure it out

File 1

```
C:\Books\Tolkien, J.R.R. - The Adventures Of Tom Bombadil.pdf
C:\Books\test.rtf.epub
C:\Books\w_E_20130215.epub
```

File 2

```
C:\Books\test.rtf.epub
C:\Books\w_E_20130215.epub
```

I want file 3 to be

```
C:\Books\Tolkien, J.R.R. - The Adventures Of Tom Bombadil.pdf
```

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` from the [DiffUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) and something like this:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>" >file3.txt
```

The output lines will be preceded by `<` or `>`, depending on which file the respective line was missing in. If you want to remove those indicators as well, use something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (
  'diff file1.txt file2.txt ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do @echo %b >>file3.txt
```

Change `%a` and `%b` into `%%a` and `%%b` if you want to run this in a batch file.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. Had to do a little tweaking (pushd and pathing) but it worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: It does appear to be generating a blank space at the end. Any way to stop it from doing that? I use the output to generate files and its creating files like this "XYZ .ext"

EDIT: NVM I changed it to do @echo %b>>file3.txt and it worked

Comment: Either that, or put the redirection at the beginning of the line: `@>>file3.txt echo %b`.

Comment: Having some more issues with this... When I try to do a diff using the same command on the following two files. It still says there is a difference https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54973965/Musicconverttemp.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54973965/DontconvertFormed.txt

The files include the same data but it seems to keep saying there are lines in one that are not in the other and vice versa

Comment: I finally figured it out... it was the sort order... I added `sort %rundir%\temp\DontConvertformed.txt >> %rundir%\temp\DontConvertformedsorted.txt
sort %rundir%\temp\Musicconverttemp.txt >> %rundir%\temp\Musicconverttempsorted.txt` and it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
FINDSTR /v /b /e /l /g:file2. file1. >file3.
```

should produce the required results - lines in file1 missing from file2.

`/v` says 'not found', `/b /e` forces exact match - not part-of-line-matches `/l` literal.

Comment: Oddly this produces C:\Books\w_E_20130215.epub

Comment: Only that line, or in addition? The last line will be reported if FILE1. does not end with a new-line. You may add e newline to file1. with `echo(>>file1.` (make sure there are two `>` characters) OR try `type file1|FINDSTR /v /b /e /l /g:file2. >file3.`